# A problem in algebra: how does $-1=1$?

Tags: exponentiation

I have algebra problem from a friend, that is 1=-1!!! because

$$-1=-1^{3}=-1^{^{\frac{6}{2}}}=\sqrt{(-1)^6}=\sqrt{1}=1$$

I can not see what is wrong with this?
 I will appreciate it any help.

Comment: Try a simpler problem $1^2=(-1)^2 \not\Rightarrow 1=-1$.

Comment: Notice that 1 has two roots: $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The usual properties of roots/exponents apply when the basis is (real) positive. In this case, we can't have

$$\;-1^3=(-1)^3=(-1)^{6/2}\color{red}{\stackrel {!!}=}\left[(-1)^{1/2}\right]^6$$

as $\;(-1)^{1/2}=\sqrt{-1}\;$  cannot be done within the real numbers (and this is also another reason why the above mentioned properties don't apply to complex numbers...)

Comment: All $-1^3$, $(-1)^3$ and $(-1)^{6/2}$ are equal! The problem is that $a^{b/c} = \sqrt[c]{a^b}$ is not always true.

Comment: @Christoph Agree with you, so I'll add. Thankx

Comment: I'd still disagree that this is the problem. Over the complex numbers $(-1)^{1/2}$ is defined as the principal square root of $-1$, which is $i$ and $i^6=-1$. The problem is that this is different from $\left[ (-1)^6 \right]^{1/2}$, which is $1$.

Comment: @Christoph Over the complex numbers it is false in general: $$1=\sqrt1=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i\cdot i=-1$$ You can't do the above, certainly. We're talking here of *general propieties* . And in the complex number I don't know of any definition **a priori** of "principal or not" branches, though many times one *usually* choses the "usual" branches.